# ld cannot find shared library even with -L specified

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, ld

I'm trying to compile a C file against a shared library at a specific location (`/home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/libInsertTimingInstr.so`), but `ld` cannot seem to find it -

```
$ gcc -g -I/home/user/tools/cuda_sync_analyzer/src/InsertTimingInstr \
         -L/home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/ \
         callback.c -o callback -lInsertTimingInstr.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lInsertTimingInstr.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried

```
$ gcc -g -I/home/user/tools/cuda_sync_analyzer/src/InsertTimingInstr \
         -L/home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/ \
         -lInsertTimingInstr.so callback.c -o callback
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lInsertTimingInstr.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

as well as setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/
$ gcc -g -I/home/user/tools/cuda_sync_analyzer/src/InsertTimingInstr \
         callback.c -o callback -lInsertTimingInstr.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lInsertTimingInstr.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The file `libInsertTimingInstr.so` is present in the directory -

```
$ ls -l /home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/ | grep Timing
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   51992 Mar 18 18:04 libInsertTimingInstr.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but ld cannot seem to find it

This command line: `gcc ... -lInsertTimingInstr.so ...` asks the linker to link against `libInsertTimingInstr.so.a` *or* `libInsertTimingInstr.so.so`, neither of which exists.

You want: `gcc ... -lInsertTimingInstr ...` (i.e. drop the `lib` prefix *and* the `.so` suffix).

Alternatively, you could do this: `gcc ... /home/user/cuda_sync_analyzer-install/lib/libInsertTimingInstr.so ...`

Comment: Thank you! It completely skipped my mind that ".so" is automatically added at the end when searching for the library.