# GCC/ld not using shared object with -l

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, ld

I've read this question: [*ld cannot find shared library even with -L specified*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749406/ld-cannot-find-shared-library-even-with-l-specified), but I'm asking a follow-up: why does GCC do this?

This is something I ran into while building a binary with links to two in-house libraries.
`gcc` cannot find the symbols from one of the libraries with `-l`, but uses the other one just fine!

Originally, the command from my Makefile was `gcc baz.o qux.o -lfoo -lbar`, with the linker unable to find the symbols from `libfoo`, while finding the symbols from `-lbar`. The libraries are the exact same type of file in the same locations: headers in `/usr/local/include` and libraries in `/usr/local/lib`. In fact, `libfoo` depends on `libbar`.

Corrected, the command is now `gcc baz.o qux.o -lbar /usr/local/lib/libfoo.so`. I have determined this is not an ordering issue.

Why does gcc need the shared object instead of an `-l`? Is there a better way to do this, other than using the absolute path? This solution seems kludgy to me.

The exact code and output I'm using are as follows:

1. [Output from using `-lsandbox`](http://paste.debian.net/1215004/)
2. [The content of `libsandbox.h`](http://paste.debian.net/1215005/)
3. [The Makefile I'm referencing, annotated.](http://paste.debian.net/1215006/)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mre]. The exact details matter.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks! I'm not sure how to reproduce this, or if there is an error in my building of the libraries; which are built the exact same way. I reckon to reproduce this would be to build my code... Nonetheless, [here](http://paste.debian.net/1215004/) is the output with `-lsandbox`, [here](http://paste.debian.net/1215005/) is the contents of `libsandbox.h`, and [here](http://paste.debian.net/1215006/) is the contents of my Makefile.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69519679/edit) the post to update it and not in comments. Please ensure the info is in the question itself and not external links. Create the smallest amount of code necessary to repro the problem - see [mre]. MREs are useful not just for posting on SO but are also a standard technique for debugging and may even lead you to find the issue yourself.

Comment: @kaylum I don't what causes this, let alone how to reproduce it. I've edited the post, though.

Comment: `-lsandbox -lmyutil -lsqlite3 db.o sandboxd.o`. Looks like the order of the args is not correct there. `-lsandbox` needs to come after `sandboxd.o`

Comment: Same issue. It isn't an ordering issue, as I've stated.

Comment: Yeah but you need to show data that doesn't have that problem. We can't just accept your assertions as by definition you don't know where the problem is. So if you show us data with obvious errors like that then it just leads to focusing on the wrong thing and wasting time.

Comment: @kaylum is on the right path - order them correctly with objects first dynamic libraries at the end with those that are dependent on others up front.

Comment: I can't read those paste files; my android doesn't cooperate with debian paste's horizontal scroll. So I'm not going to be able to help. But I have a small question. You seem to be capable of pasting text into a online paste service. What exactly prevents you from pasting into your question, as you have been requested to do? SO policy, as indicated in the help pages, requires that questions be self-contained. Among the reasons is precisely that it makes it easier for us to read them.

Comment: I am inclined to guess that `libfoo.so` is built incorrectly.  For example, perhaps it is a static library with the name of a shared one.  That could explain why the linker doesn't find it with `-lfoo`, but naming it via its full path makes the overall link succeed.

Comment: regarding: $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(OBJS) -o $@
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(OBJS) /usr/local/lib/libsandbox.so -o $@  the linker processes the command in the order written.  so when the `$(LDLIBS)) parameter is processed, the objects are not yet processed, so there are no unresolved external references to be resolved.  The result is (it seems) to be ignoring the libraries,